# My keyboard on Latitude D520 stopped working

Tags: keyboard, dell-latitude

I had Win 7 on the machine. The keyboard stopped working after being unused for 3 months. I installed Win10 without a problem. Still the same problem. I have an external keyboard, wireless. Same problem.

I tried FN-keys and Num-lock key. No change.

What is next? Since it is on both keyboards, it cannot be something on the physical built in keyboard.